# AzureDevops build agents - Can one agent pool have multiple agents build using different PATs?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have working local Agent Pool (deploy) which already have 4 agents. They run ok but i need to add more agents. However i don't know the PAT that was used to create those agents.
I am now using a different account to create another agent and it is created ok. But the pipelines that are using the Agent Pool (deploy) are not picking this new agent!
Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The PAT is only used to create the agent's first auth session. Afterwards it sets up a new secure token.

You can setup agents with as many PATs as you'd like.

Comment: can it also be on two different versions as i have shown above? It is not picking the new agent i just created even though it was ON and Online.

Comment: Versions shouldn't matter either.